# How to set Xamarin iOS UITableView Reorder icon color

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

How can I change the color of the reorder icon on a UITableView cell when editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `UITableViewCell` whose reorder icon color you wish to change. Override `SetEditing` with the following code.

```
public override void SetEditing(bool editing, bool animated)
{
    base.SetEditing(editing, animated);
    if (editing)
    {
        foreach (var subViewA in Subviews)
        {
            if (subViewA.IsMemberOfClass(new ObjCRuntime.Class("UITableViewCellReorderControl")))
            {
                foreach (var subViewB in subViewA.Subviews)
                {
                    if (subViewB is UIImageView imageView)
                    {
                        imageView.Image = imageView.Image = imageView.Image.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate);
                        imageView.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```